# Quick question on RandomForestClassifier parameters from Scikit Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am attempting to maximise the accuracy of a RandomForestClassifier that categorises negative and positive customer reviews using GridSearchCV. However, I am unsure what most hyperparameters from RandomForestClassifier do. Which parameters have the most effect on the accuracy of the model?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n_estimators` and `max_depth` can help you increase the accuracy. I also recommend you to read Random Forest Classifier document [Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) to understand the function of each parameter because every parameter has some impact on your model.